# is there a way to provide license key while installing .msi applications using powershell?

Tags: docker, powershell

I am trying to install few applications on mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019 using .msi files

I have license keys for some applications (wordglue, abcpdf). Is there a way I can install these applications with the license keys that I have?

I have tried to use
`msiexec .\wordglue.msi pidkey="license_key"` and

`Import-Module WordGlue Set-WordGlueLicenseKey -LicenseKey "YourLicenseKeyGoesHere"`

But nothing seems to work. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: "nothing seems to work" - are you getting any errors? :)

Comment: it is automatically opening the Windows Installer guide.

Comment: Are you missing the /i option?  Check error logs.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng /i tells msiexec to "normally" install the app. Product code is a GUID for app. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** No, there is not.

**Long answer:** No, there is no way to achieve it. Documentation doesn't see this either: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec
This is a known issue and known fact and a big downside of msi packages.

**But!**

There is a chance to do it using Orca. You'd need to include this as a parameter, don't want to paste random Google searches, so will leave it to you. :)

Comment: If the msi file supports a pidkey property, it should work, assuming they're running "msiexec /i".

Comment: no, it's not accepting the pidkey property.